# Call forEach on a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am not that experienced in JS so maybe this is a very naive question. 
I tried to call

```
"".forEach((e, i) => {
    console.log(e)
})
```

And I get an error saying that `forEach` is not a function for a string. Yet when I call:

```
Object.getOwnProperyNames("")
```

I can clearly see that `forEach()` is in the prototype of the string and of type `function`.

Why can I not call it on a string?

Comment: You can't use it on a string because it's not available on the String prototype.

Comment: `I can clearly see that forEach() is in the prototype of the string and of type function.` where you can see this, `forEach` is not available on String

Comment: The array returned from `.getOwnPropertyNames()` has a `.forEach` method because it's an array.

Comment: What do you expect to be logged in that inner function? Why **should** a string have a `forEach` function?

Comment: Sidebar: Isn't `Object.getOwnProperyNames("")` not the correct way to do this anyway? Shouldn't it be `cObject.getOwnPropertyNames(String.prototype)`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Object.getOwnPropertyNames` returns an array, and you can iterate through an array - no surprises there.

As for iterating through a string with a `forEach` loop, you can't - you can only use a `for` loop. That is, iterating through a *string*. A quick and easy way to use `forEach` is to spread the string into an array:

```
[..."Hello, World!"].forEach((e, i) => console.log(e));
```

Or, if it contains certain characters:

```
Array.from("Hello, World!").forEach((e, i) => console.log(e));
```

Comment: This works as described in the browser console but I can't get it to compile in my IDE.

Comment: This is no criticism of the answer, but using the spread operator or Array.from would convert the string to an array via the charAt method, no? Or require a method of iteration for each character in some way. If that's the case, I question the value of performing a duplicate operation that could be done with a single loop.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.getOwnPropertyNames("")` only returns `["length"]`. The .foreach you're seeing, I assume in Inspector, is a property of the array returned (ie. you could call `["length"].foreach(...)`). It does not imply that string has a foreach method.